# Same API Key for sending notification via GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to implement GCM notification feature in my app. But I have two apps with different app package names. Is possible to use same API key for both apps?

Also I want to know, if it is possible, is it required to have both apps on Google store? Isn't it possible to have one app on Google store and other on some other app distributor channel?

Thanks,

Comment: If this is an Android key, I believe you cannot. An android key requires an sha-1 fingerprint and package name. Though you can use the same sha-1 fingerprint, since you have two different apps with two different package names, you'll have to create a key for each. You can however keep both keys in the same project, but I think it's better to have them separate for the sake of each application having its own set of quota. Whether or not you want to publish on the Play Store is entirely up to you. It won't affect the usage for **most** Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple applications can receive downstream messages from the same server (with single API key), The clients have to register to notify GCM which server they want to receive messages from.

On Android GCM is part of Google Play Services. The device must have Google Play Services in order to use GCM. Generally this means Google Play Store only.